Query ONLY Most Recent Rows
I have the following SQL which isn't doing what I expected - it is supposed to only query the latest row for each ITEMID based on STARTDATE, I am only interested in the most recent of each.  This seems to be returning other rows, not sure why.
WITH GA as (
    SELECT LABEL, ITEMID, STARTDATE, UNIT, UNITTYPE, BUILDING, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITEMID ORDER BY STARTDATE ASC) AS rn,
           CASE
                WHEN UNIT is NULL THEN 'Unit Null'
                WHEN UNIT is not NULL then 'Type Null'
                ELSE 'Other'
           END AS WP
    FROM GLA
    WHERE LABEL = 'CUSTOMER'
    AND ((UNIT is not NULL and UNITTYPE is NULL)
         OR (UNIT is NULL and UNITTYPE is not NULL)
    )
)
SELECT *
FROM GA
WHERE rn > 1




ITEMID
STARTDATE
UNIT
UNITTYPE
BUILDING




123
2016-01-06 00:00:00.000
NULL
NULL
Home


123
2020-01-06 00:00:00.000
NULL
Unit
Away


567
2019-01-06 00:00:00.000
NULL
NULL
Friday


888
NULL
10B
NULL
York



There can be multiple rows for ITEMID but I am only interested in the most recent one, hope that is clear.
How can I fix my code or is it totally broken?  I got this by searching around the net so apologies if it's rubbish but thanks for any help!
(For the data given it should return the second and fourth rows as that's most recent and fits the criteria, but STARTDATE can be NULL as well)
Thanks for any help,

You are on the right track. I believe you need ORDER BY STARTDATE DESC so that the latest date has rn = 1. Then filter for rn = 1.

The issue is that you select all rows where rn>1, which means you get all rows except the first one for each ITEMID. However, you want the only latest rows for each ITEMID, which is the row with the highest STARTDATE.
Here is the corrected query:
WITH GA as (
    SELECT LABEL, ITEMID, STARTDATE, UNIT, UNITTYPE, BUILDING, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITEMID ORDER BY STARTDATE DESC) AS rn,
           CASE
                WHEN UNIT is NULL THEN 'Unit Null'
                WHEN UNIT is not NULL then 'Type Null'
                ELSE 'Other'
           END AS WP
    FROM GLA
    WHERE LABEL = 'CUSTOMER'
    AND ((UNIT is not NULL and UNITTYPE is NULL)
         OR (UNIT is NULL and UNITTYPE is not NULL)
    )
)
SELECT *
FROM GA
WHERE rn = 1

This query will return only the latest row for each ITEMID() based on the STARTDATE.
Here Is a document form Microsoft how to get latest data: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/832731/get-the-data-of-only-latest-date-and-time-stamp-fr

I would be interesting for you to explain how this differs from your other answer and why the question differs from at least 250 other questions closed as a duplicate of the canonical duplicate.
